# adding buttons below the other

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to add buttons one below the other. I have this simple code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    for(int i=0 ; i<9 ; i++)
    {
        UIButton *myButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
        myButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height/10); //this "10" i want also dynamically
        myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [self.view addSubview:myButton];
    }

}
```

Of course i know that it will be draw one on another. But can i do it in the loop **without knowing the height** (becouse high will depends on how many buttons will be in the loop).

What i want to achieve:

[image: Buttons]

Comment: But if you add 100 buttons, they'll be a bit small,no ? Why do you not add buttons into an uiscrollview ?

Comment: if I figure it out how to add one below another this will not be an issue to add scrollview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
  {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    int number = 10;

     for(int i=0 ; i<9 ; i++)
    {
    UIButton *myButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    myButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, (self.view.frame.size.height/number)*i + number, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height/number);
    myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.view addSubview:myButton];
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this might work? Sorry I haven't used `self.view.frame` in ages, but you get the general idea.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    int number;

    for(int i=0 ; i<9 ; i++)
    {
        UIButton *myButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
        myButton.frame = CGRectMake(i * self.view.frame.origin.x / number,
                                    self.view.frame.origin.y,
                                    self.view.frame.size.width,
                                    self.view.frame.size.height / number); //this "10" i want also dynamically
        myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [self.view addSubview:myButton];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to define the size of the buttons for the correct show, unfortunately **without the size of the buttons you cannot achieve you wished** because *how else does the system know what sized button you'd like to show...?*

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    Float32 _spaceBetweenButtons = 8.f;
    Float32 _offsetY = 32.f;
    Float32 _buttonWidth = 300.f; // width fo button
    Float32 _buttonHeight = 32.f; // height of the button

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 9 ; i++) {
        UIButton *_myButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, _buttonWidth, _buttonHeight)];
        [_myButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [_myButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"button #%d", i] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; // just add some text as title
        [self.view addSubview:_myButton];
        [_mybutton setCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2.f, _offsetY + i * (myButton.frame.size.height + _spaceBetweenButtons))];
    }
}
```

---

if you want to calculate the size of the buttons dynamically and you want to align the button's height to the view's height, here would be one way:

```
NSInteger _numberOfButtons = 20;
Float32 _spaceBetweenButtons = 8.f;
Float32 _calculatedHeight = (self.view.frame.size.height - (_numberOfButtons + 1 * _spaceBetweenButtons)) / _numberOfButtons;
```

and the method is same as above, but I'm not sure you will get good UI in case of hundreds buttons. :)